# How to pass in a lambda and have access to a particular set of methods

Tags: c#, lambda, action, anonymous-function, func

I want to have something like:

```
 AStaticClass.MakeCall(commonCmds => commonCmds.MethodOfAParticularClass)
```

So I want to have a lambda expression as an argument and have the delegate list the available set of methods of a particular class that I can access through intellisense with the lambda function. Then make a call to the passed in method.

i.e. `commonCmds => commonCmds. {Lists all the methods of a particular class}`

and then I want to have a method that makes that call.

I can't figure it out the proper method signature.

So far I have public void `MakeCall(Action cmd) {cmd.invoke;}` THis obviously does not work. I tried func, Expression and cannot figure it out.

Thank you so much for the help!

EDIT:

CmdsTwo and CmdsOne Can be static. However I would like to my classes up in this way, since it will make a lot my other work much easier.

```
public void Main(string []args) {
    MyStaticClass.MakeCall(x => x.DoThis);

    MyStaticClass.MakeCallTwo(x => x.DoThisTwo);

    MyStaticClass.MakeCall(x => x.DoThisThree);
}

public static class MyStaticClass{
    public static void MakeCall<???>( ??????)

    public static void MakeCallTwo<???>( ??????)
}

public class Cmds{
    public void DoThis();

    public void DoThisThree();
}

public class CmdsTwo{
    public void DoThisTwo();
}
```

}

Comment: 'have the delegate list the available set of methods of a particular class that I can access' does not make sense. Are you talking about Intellisense?

Comment: Answers are pretty different, you should make more clear what you mean with _list all the methods of a particular class_.

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what you're asking.  Are you saying Do you want the IDE to know what type you're passing to your `MakeCall` method so that intellisense works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it. Iused an extension method. Thank you.

```
 public static class MyStaticClass{
     public static void MakeCall(Action<Cmds> paramater){
           Helper(new Cmds(), parameter);
      }

      private static void Helper(this Cmds, Action<Cmds> invokeThis) {...}

     public static void MakeCallTwo<???>( ??????)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest i can think of right now is this:

```
commonCmds => commonCmds.GetType().GetMethods()
```

This returns you an array of [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx), which describe all methods of the type of `commonCmds`. You'd have to invoke one of those like this:

```
object result = someMethodInfo.Invoke(someObjectInstance, new object[] { someParameter });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it

```
AStaticClass.MakeCall( () => commonCmds.MethodOfAParticularClass)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the generic version of Action With A Type.

```
public void MakeCall(Action<TYPE_HERE> cmd) 
{
   cmd.Invoke(...);
}
```

The type gets inferred and intellisense should kick in.